# batch file with user input to open a url

Tags: batch-file, variables, input

Totally new here and green to coding.
I have I new job task that requires a specific url were only the last 4 nubbers/letter change.
how can I do a batch file to have a user input open a specific url with said input inserted into last 4.

example http:://1234::56:ab78: then user input.?

I have gateways for access control that I have to login to like a router. just I could have 200 of them and only the last four digits change. so I'm trying to simplify having to type in a long mac address to ipv6 into I windows web page to help my guys in the field. example this has to be typed in url- http://[fe80::217:7:aff:fe0f:0005]. but say the next gateway is 0006, when they type the 4 numbers into the batch prompt I need it to put in in that spot then proceed with url and enter. thanks for your time. thanks in advance, ill keep searching till I figure this out.

Comment: Great! as soon as you've got some code and tried it, we're here to help. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50195175/edit), and add the code, _(not forgetting to format it using the `{}` button)_, with a description of what happened when you ran it.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like http://www.url.com?qn=`[user inputted number]`?

You can do the trick by this:

```
@echo off
rem not really necessary for this part
title open our company's website
color de
mode con: cols=90 lines=25
rem below is necessary
goto t

:t
set str=error
set /p str=Please enter four characters: 
set len=0
goto sl

:sl
call set this=%%str:~%len%%%
if not "%this%" == "" (set /a len+=1
goto :sl)
if not "%len%" == "4" (echo Sorry but please input four characters to open a website. Press any key to type in again.
pause >nul
cls
goto t)
start http://www.url.com?qn=%str%
echo URL opened, press any key to leave.
pause >nul
exit
```

Special thanks to inspiration brought by [Tutorial Spot](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_string_length.htm)
.
Sadly the codes here cannot prevent users to type in characters such as ", &, |, etc., which may cause scripting errors to the batch because I cannot be sure does your company had links that include the following characters. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Sorry if the answer doesn't suit your need. I wanted to ask you for further information in the comment but the system blocked me, please reply at the comment of this answer or else I can't reply...

Comment: maybe, I have gateways for access control that I have to login to like a router. just I could have 200 of them and only the last four digits change. so I'm trying to simplify having to type in a long mac address to ipv6 into I windows web page to help my guys in the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /p "prefix=IP6 prefix: " || exit /b 1
set "suffix=0001"
set /p "suffix=IP6 suffix: "
if not "%prefix:~-1%" == ":" set "prefix=%prefix%:"
set "count=1"
set /p "count=Repetition count: "
set /a "limit=0x%suffix%+count-1"

:loop
echo.
echo start %prefix%%suffix%
call :hex_increment suffix "%suffix%"
if 0x%suffix% gtr %limit% (
    echo Repetition count reached
    exit /b 0
)
set "reply=y"
set /p "reply=Continue? [y|n]: "
if /i "%reply%" == "y" goto :loop
exit /b

:hex_increment
setlocal
set /a "_dec=0x%~2+1"
cmd /c exit /b %_dec%
set "_hex=%=ExitCode:~4%"
endlocal & set "%~1=%_hex%"
exit /b
```

The *IP6 prefix* is i.e. `http://fe80::217:7:aff:fe0f` and
the *IP6 suffix* is i.e. `0007`.

*IP6 prefix* is required so pressing only <kbd>return</kbd>
will exit the script.

*IP6 suffix* is optional and the default is `0001`.

The trailing `:` will be appended to the *IP6 prefix* if missing.

The *Repetition count* is i.e. `200` limit of urls to output.

*Repetition count* is optional and defaults to `1`.

The `:loop` label echoes the command that you want to use
with the first url. Then a call to the label `:hex_increment`
increments +1 the hexidecimal number of `%suffix%` which will
update `%suffix%`.

A prompt will ask to continue and repeat the loop, else exits.
Default reply to continue is `y`.

Example output:

```
IP6 prefix: http://fe80::217:7:aff:fe0f
IP6 suffix: 0007
Repetition count: 5

start http://fe80::217:7:aff:fe0f:0007
Continue? [y|n]:

start http://fe80::217:7:aff:fe0f:0008
Continue? [y|n]:

start http://fe80::217:7:aff:fe0f:0009
Continue? [y|n]:

start http://fe80::217:7:aff:fe0f:000A
Continue? [y|n]:

start http://fe80::217:7:aff:fe0f:000B
Repetition count reached
```

If `start http://...` is the desired command then just
remove the leading `echo` keyword to use, else change
to what you prefer.

Comment: thanks very much, this is getting me in the right direction. will update when I can get to working on this more.